# Connecting Codeiginter App to an external mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an external database which i normally connect to using SSH tunnel on `sequel Pro with` the below credentials

**Details**

```
Mysql Host  : 127.0.0.1
Username : myname
Password : password
database:  optional
port: 3306

SSH Host: 10.00.00.00
SSH User:  user_name
SSH Pass: password_external
Port: optional
```

When i connect with sequel pro with the above details, the connection is successful. However, when i try to connect to the external/remote database from my Codeiginter APP with the below details, it fails to connect

$active_group = 'mydb';
    $query_builder = TRUE;

```
$db['mydb']['hostname'] = '10.00.00.00';
$db['mydb']['username'] = 'user_name';
$db['mydb']['password'] = 'password_external';
$db['mydb']['database'] = '';
$db['mydb']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['mydb']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['mydb']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['mydb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['mydb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['mydb']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['mydb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['mydb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['mydb']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['mydb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['mydb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Please assist. I can't tell why it fails to connect from my application.

Comment: Any error messages from the framework?

Comment: it just says could not connect to database @user1597430

Comment: Where's the rest of that configuration? Using the given one, you try to connect to a MySQL database which listens on `10.00.00.00`, which is not the same as a database listening on `127.0.0.1`  over an SSH tunnel

Comment: @NicoHaase, even when i listen to '127.0.0.1', it returns the same error. Do i have to configure the SSH in the configuration ?